# Таймер, который не ждет sleep

Tags: python, mysql, aiogram

Я пишу боту на Python aiogram, и мне нужно написать код, который выполнится через некоторое время. Я написал это:

```
text = '*Напишу через 15 секунд*'
# mysql запрос
await message.answer(text, reply_markup=playing_session, parse_mode='Markdown')
time.sleep(15)
text = '*Написал*'
# mysql запрос
await message.answer(text, reply_markup=playing_session, parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Но у этого кода есть минус - если во время sleep написать боту, он ничего не скажет, а будет ждать окончание sleep. Меня это не устраивает.

Comment: Возможно вы ищете это - https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html
обычный time.sleep - это блокирующая функция

Answer (score 2):

Ты можешь просто использовать asyncio

```
import asyncio
```

И вместо time.sleep(15) используй

```
await asyncio.sleep(15)
```